# whenever i run the app on emulator it says unfortunately the app has stopped working and the log reads as below

Tags: android

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.intel.dualboot;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StatusAsyncTask.StatusAsyncTaskListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, MainActivityListener {
    private static final String TAG = "db::MainActivity";

   /* public static final int ACT_INSTALL_ROM        = 1;
    public static final int ACT_CHANGE_PAGE        = 2;
    public static final int ACT_SELECT_ICON        = 3;
    public static final int ACT_UNINSTALL_ROM      = 4;

    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST = "show_rom_list";*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 20) {
            showDeprecatedLAlert();
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // This activity is using different background color, which would cause overdraw
        // of the whole area, so disable the default background
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

        Utils.installHttpCache(this);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);

        m_srLayout = (InSwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
        m_srLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        m_curFragment = -1;

        m_fragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_fragment_titles);
        m_drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        m_drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        String[] fragmentClsNames = new String[MainFragment.MAIN_FRAG_CNT];
        for(int i = 0; i < fragmentClsNames.length; ++i)
            fragmentClsNames[i] = MainFragment.getFragmentClass(i).getName();

        m_fragments = new MainFragment[MainFragment.MAIN_FRAG_CNT];
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i) {
            m_fragments[i] = (MainFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentClsNames[i]);
            if(m_fragments[i] == null) {
                m_fragments[i] = MainFragment.newFragment(i);
                t.add(R.id.content_frame, m_fragments[i], fragmentClsNames[i]);
            }
            t.hide(m_fragments[i]);
        }
        t.commit();

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        m_drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list, m_fragmentTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        m_drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


        m_drawerTitle = getText(R.string.app_name);
        m_drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, m_drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(m_title);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(m_drawerTitle);
            }
        };
        m_drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(m_drawerToggle);

        final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(bar != null) {
            bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

      /*  if (getIntent().hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST) &&
                getIntent().getBooleanExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST, false)) {
            getIntent().removeExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST);
            selectItem(1);
        } else if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            selectItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("curFragment", 0));
        } else {
            selectItem(0);
        }*/
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
        super.onNewIntent(i);
        if (i.hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST) &&
                i.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST, false)) {
            selectItem(1);
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Utils.flushHttpCache();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("curFragment", m_curFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        m_refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        if(!StatusAsyncTask.instance().isComplete())
            m_refreshItem.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        if(position < 0 || position >= m_fragments.length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid fragment index " + position);
            return;
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if(m_curFragment != -1)
            t.hide(m_fragments[m_curFragment]);
        t.show(m_fragments[position]);
        t.commit();

        m_curFragment = position;

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        m_drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(m_fragmentTitles[position]);
        m_drawerLayout.closeDrawer(m_drawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        m_title = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(m_title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(m_drawerToggle != null)
            m_drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(m_drawerToggle != null)
            m_drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem it) {
        if (m_drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(it))
            return true;

        switch(it.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                refresh(false);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_reboot:
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                b.setTitle("Reboot")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .setItems(R.array.reboot_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                switch (i) {
                                    case 0: Utils.reboot(""); break;
                                    case 1: Utils.reboot("recovery"); break;
                                    case 2: Utils.reboot("bootloader"); break;
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .create().show();
                return true;
            }

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void startRefresh(boolean notifyRefreshLayout) {
        if(notifyRefreshLayout)
            m_srLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        if(m_refreshItem != null)
            m_refreshItem.setEnabled(false);

        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i)
            m_fragments[i].startRefresh();

        StatusAsyncTask.instance().setListener(this);
        StatusAsyncTask.instance().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void refresh(boolean b) {
        refresh(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRefreshComplete() {
        m_srLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        if(m_refreshItem != null)
            m_refreshItem.setEnabled(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i)
            m_fragments[i].setRefreshComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentViewCreated() {
        if(++m_fragmentViewsCreated == m_fragments.length) {
            // postDelayed because SwipeRefresher view ignores
            // setRefreshing call otherwise
            m_srLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    if(i == null || !i.getBooleanExtra("force_refresh", false)) {
                        startRefresh(true);
                    } else {
                        i.removeExtra("force_refresh");
                        refresh(false);
                    }
                }
            }, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentViewDestroyed() {
        --m_fragmentViewsCreated;
    }

    @Override
    public void addScrollUpListener(InSwipeRefreshLayout.ScrollUpListener l) {
        m_srLayout.addScrollUpListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusTaskFinished(StatusAsyncTask.Result res) {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i)
            m_fragments[i].onStatusTaskFinished(res);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refresh(false);
    }

    @TargetApi(20)
    private void showDeprecatedLAlert() {
        SpannableString msg = new SpannableString("Android Developer preview has bugs");
        Linkify.addLinks(msg, Linkify.ALL);

        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setTitle("Unsupported Android version")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setNegativeButton("Exit Application", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog d = b.create();
        d.show();

        TextView msgView = (TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        msgView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

    private DrawerLayout m_drawerLayout;
    private ListView m_drawerList;
    private String[] m_fragmentTitles;
    private MainFragment[] m_fragments;
    private int m_curFragment;
    private CharSequence m_title;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle m_drawerToggle;
    private CharSequence m_drawerTitle;
    private MenuItem m_refreshItem;
    private int m_fragmentViewsCreated;
    private InSwipeRefreshLayout m_srLayout;




}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/lviewdimen"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Stack Trace

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.example.intel.dualboot, PID: 23319
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.intel.dualboot/com.example.intel.dualboot.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field
>   'android.app.FragmentManagerImpl
>   android.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2330)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field
>   'android.app.FragmentManagerImpl
>   android.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
>                                                          at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:469)
>                                                          at android.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:464)
>                                                          at com.example.intel.dualboot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Comment: InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class , check the package name of your XML line 8

Comment: can you post your InSwiperefresh implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
com.exmaple.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout
```

with

```
android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```

in your xml file,
as the com.exmaple.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout class is not defined

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intel.dualboot/com.example.intel.dualboot.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout cannot be cast to com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout cannot be cast to com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: @AshishYadav Your code looks fine to me, since you are creating a custom SwipeRefreshLayout, you will have to pass com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout, as you are doing. Try cleaning your project once !!

Comment: @AshishYadav from the logcat the class was not found, I thought you didn't declare the custom view class, try rebuilding your project now

Comment: @AshishYadav however if you don't need the custom class you could use my answer but you have to cast the view in the main activity to (SwipeRefreshLayout) and the type of the "m_srLayout" also to (SwipeRefreshLayout)

Comment: hey I've updated the code and now I'm facing this error

Comment: @AshishYadav This is another issue,  however this may be the result of passing a null as a fragment, try checking for nulls before starting the transaction

Comment: @kareemadel please be specific and suggest a solution

Comment: @AshishYadav double check this part in the for loop 
m_fragments[i] = (MainFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentClsNames[i]);
            if(m_fragments[i] == null) {
                m_fragments[i] = MainFragment.newFragment(i);
                t.add(R.id.content_frame, m_fragments[i], fragmentClsNames[i]);
            }
            t.hide(m_fragments[i]);
(where m_fragments[i] is not null)

Comment: @AshishYadav as hiding a null fragment can cause this error

Answer (score 0):

```
com.exmaple.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout
```

Check this path if it is correct in your xml.It seems the path of "InSwipeRefreshLayout" is not corect

Answer (score 0):

in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<com.exmaple.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</com.exmaple.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout>
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/lviewdimen"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the `com.exmaple.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout` has that spelling of "exmaple", it should be example.

Answer (score 0):

The posted layout working fine for me.Please check the package name properly com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout whether exist or not and clean and build the project.